# Check status information on services of Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to check the status of services that are part of Google Cloud respectively from all this services: [Service health GCP](https://status.cloud.google.com/index.html). I am new to GCP and was wondering how to check it with for example Cloud Functions etc. Can someone give me any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to check the status of services ...

You can determine the status of a service by processing the health data. This is not as simple as it might appear as there is no indicator for a service's health at this instant, only historical data of events.

Google Cloud publishes the JSON schema for Google Cloud Service Health:

[Google Cloud Service Health JSON Schema](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.schema.json)

Example:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "title": "Incidents",
  "type": "array",
  "description": "Incident in the public status dashboard",
  "items": {
    ...
```

You can fetch the health data from this endpoint:

https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents.json

Example data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "yatPQDmQ5uXqb6PzwanU",
    "number": "13941430952028707728",
    "begin": "2022-04-23T02:10:00+00:00",
    "created": "2022-04-23T16:27:43+00:00",
    "end": "2022-04-23T17:21:00+00:00",
    "modified": "2022-04-25T20:06:04+00:00",
    "external_desc": "Global: Cloud Monitoring Metrics may be unavailable or underreported for Cloud Pub/Sub",
    "updates": [
      {
        "created": "2022-04-25T20:05:32+00:00",
        "modified": "2022-04-25T20:05:32+00:00",
        "when": "2022-04-25T20:05:32+00:00",
        "text": "We apologize for the inconvenience this service ...
```

Comment: Thank you John! Is there an automatic way fetch the health data in GCP?

Comment: @zenubeh What do you mean by **automatic**? Your program must make a request to read the data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, on how to do that respectively can you give me any advice on how my program can read that data?

Comment: @zenubeh - create a new question. Your original question has been answered. To understand how to read an endpoint, create a question asking that. One question/problem per post. Do not forget to accept this answer so that the question does not stay unsolved forever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Creating a service-level indicator](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/slo-monitoring/api/identifying-custom-sli)

If you create custom services, then you must also create service-level objectives (SLOs) for them. There are no pre-defined SLOs for custom services.

You can also create custom SLOs for automatically detected services, but that is less common.

SLOs are built on top of metrics that measure performance and are used as service-level indicators (SLIs). For custom SLOs, you must identify the metrics you want to use in your SLIs.

[SLO monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/slo-monitoring)

Automatically infer or custom define service-level objectives (SLOs) for applications and get alerted when SLO violations occur.